# Not seeing all views in views using views.addSubviews

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview

I am running into a basic problem with views on iPad. I have a viewController. The view is using a UIImageView with a full screen image as a background image. I am trying to overlay labels on the top. If I set labels individually, both views show up. If I call a function with the same information only one view shows up. I need to extend it many labels. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backGroundImageView: UIImageView!
var cFrame:[CGRect?] = [CGRect?](repeating: nil, count: 13)
var offsets:[CGRect?] = [CGRect?](repeating: nil, count: 13)
var labels: [UILabel?] = [UILabel?](repeating:UILabel(), count:13)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cFrame[0] = CGRect(x:450,y:530,width:251,height:68)
    cFrame[1] = CGRect(x:147,y:676,width:222,height:24)

    loadFrameValues()


    var frame = CGRect(x: 450, y: 520, width: 251, height: 68)
    let label0 = UILabel(frame: frame)
    label0.backgroundColor = .white
    label0.numberOfLines = 0
    label0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label0.textAlignment = .center
    label0.text = "Text 1"

    frame = CGRect(x: 152, y: 686, width: 210, height: 16)
    let label1 = UILabel(frame: frame)

    label1.backgroundColor = .cyan
    label1.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label1.textAlignment = .left
    label1.text = "Text 2"
    label1.font = label1.font.withSize(12)

    backGroundImageView.addSubview(label0)
    backGroundImageView.addSubview(label1)

   //        showView(label: labels[0]!, frame: cFrame[0]!)
     //        showView(label: labels[1]!, frame: cFrame[1]!)
    //        }



}

func showView(label: UILabel, frame:CGRect) {
    label.frame = frame
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "Syed Tariq"
    backGroundImageView.addSubview(label)

}
```

Comment: stop using frames and start using constraints just an advice .

Comment: you probably added two labels but they have same frames?

Comment: Pls, show the original code where you are having the problem

Comment: This is the code above. You can see the frame specs in the code (not the same frame), What you see in the code works. When I substitute the function showView, it shows only the first view. Also, tried adding to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add subview (label in your case) to UIImageView. So add label as subview to the superview of your image view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    cFrame[0] = CGRect(x:50,y:130,width:151,height:68)
    cFrame[1] = CGRect(x:114,y:276,width:122,height:24)
    showView(frame: cFrame[0]!)
    showView(frame: cFrame[1]!)
}

func showView(frame:CGRect) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "Syed Tariq"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

}
```

Comment: Does not make a difference but is undoubdtedly the right thing to do.

Comment: Edited the above code, which is working fine. No need to declare the array of labels, and changed the CGRect frame because it was going out of the window.

Comment: If you want to define the labels array, initially initialize with nil. From showView method, return the label instance and append it to your labels array.